# Executing single TestNG test case with using Maven/Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

Can anyone tell me how to execute single testcase with maven or jenkins. 
    `mvn -Dtest=smoke` tests seem to be not working for me. 
    I have tried other options like `mvn` clean install `-Dtest=smoketest` test that time i got below error if  is set to true, and no tests execute if set to false`
        Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project ABC: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)

**POM USED**

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.testng.smoke</groupId>
    <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build> <!-- Source directory configuration -->
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins> <!-- plugins executes the testng tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <AppName>XYX</AppName>
                        <browserName>chrome</browserName>
                        <isLocal>true</isLocal>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <groups>${chooseGroup}</groups>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be usedfor compiling the code -->

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: you mean you want to execute single test method?

Comment: Yes Maciej , Is it possible to do that with Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt matter if its jenkins or local build.

You have to specify you test in the following way:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClass#testmethod test
```

You forgot about that #.

Comment: I've tried this option too, I get  No tests were executed! (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) , Have added <includes>
               <include>**.java</include>
               </includes> in the POM.  Should I modify anything in POM?

Comment: include your pom.. the pacaking and the plugins section especially

Comment: <groupId>com.testng.smoke</groupId>
  <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging> <properties>
     <suiteFile>TestNG.xml</suiteFile> 
     <chooseGroup></chooseGroup>
     <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>1.4.24.RC2</allure.version>
  </properties>  
  <dependencies> 
   <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: @SS89 can you update the question with you with above POM part and TestNG.xml. it's hard to read here.

Comment: <plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.19.1</version><configuration>
 <systemPropertyVariables><AppName>XYX</AppName>
<browserName>chrome</browserName><isLocal>true</isLocal>
</systemPropertyVariables><suiteXmlFiles><suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile</suiteXmlFiles><groups>${chooseGroup}</groups> <includes> <include>**.java</include> </includes>                     
 <properties><property><name>suitethreadpoolsize</name<value>5</value>
</property></properties>        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>

Comment: @SS89 can you please update the question, rather than putting things here in comment?

Comment: try to specify full name of class with package

Comment: @SS89 how about testng.xml file? can you put a snipped as well. also, are you able to run all the tests in particular suite file. I mean if you create a testng.xml file with just one class are you able to run all the tests in that class?